# Storing thousands of disabled docker containers so that they can be searched and ran within a reasonable amount of time.

Tags: database, docker, schema, storage

These containers need to be (relatively, within 500ms) searchable and related to a container UID, account username, and other data points. Thanks in advance for the help. Each container will most likely be within 250-500mb. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, your question is receiving a lot of negative responses. It really looks like you've just asked a question without learning much about SO and what it's for. A lot of stuff like this turns up, and almost nobody has the time available to help new users who may become useful active members of this community. But today I've got a few minutes spare, so you're getting a nice response rather than just finding your question closed without comment...

Comment: You've got a problem of some sort, we can start by having you state that at the top of your question. Then you've got a specific question, so that should go somewhere near the top too. Then you should explain the context of your problem. You should demonstrate that you've done some research and address the results and why they're not helpful. You should also look at similar questions on SO to find out if they already have a useful answer.

Comment: And, finally, you'll have to go into a lot more detail on this one. Please read [ask] and then try again with something a bit more specific. Thanks. Also, you have apparently added random tags to your question -- what does schema have to do with anything? Or databases? This looks like a docker question, and nothing else.